# Team Fortress 2 doesn't work in version 17.04

Tags: intel-graphics, steam, 17.04

So basically, I can't get TF2 to work. I recently switched over to 17.04 and TF2 won't load graphics wise. I was also having crash issues on 16.04.

I've tried using the windows version running WINE and it will load the graphics but it seems to be stuck in a weird display format that is unplayable. Using the following command -h "Your monitors height" -w "Your monitor's width" in the launch settings fixes the issue entirely. Meaning that WINE is the only working version right now. However alt-tabbing will crash the game.

The player models will then glitch out as well while running the WINE version. But it's at least playable in comparison.

This is what my graphics currently look like. If I load up a game then it also displays everything in black. Reinstalling hasn't fixed the issue.

Using an I5-7500 3.0ghz. 8 GB of DDR4 RAM. And a 1 TB WD Blue HDD. With an ASUS HM110-E/m.2 Motherboard.

https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1114739202

Comment: Hardware specs, namely graphics?

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: TF2 for SteamOS/Ubuntu requires *nVidia GeForce 8600/9600GT, ATI/AMD Radeon HD2600/3600 (Graphic Drivers: nVidia 310, AMD 12.11), OpenGL 2.1*. For Window it uses DirectX and have lower requirements. So, if you're only using integrated Intel Graphics... I doubt it was working before but you tell us.

Comment: TF2 is famously known for being the game that can be "ran on a toaster oven." I've used in IGPU on several other computers running TF2 flawlessly. Even an old intel core 2 duo processor was able to run TF2 on an IGPU. And I have ran an older laptop on Ubuntu in TF2 without any problems.

Comment: Please check the hardware requirements at Steam. You'll notice they are quite different in Windows and in Linux.

Comment: Yeah but I've used this PC setup before. And the crashes on 16.04 specifically didn't start until fairly recently. The graphical issues are specific to 17.04 and do not occur in 16.04. Until about two weeks ago, I was able to run flawlessly on 16.04 then it started to crash for no reason. And not to mention that I had a 2010 ubuntu 16.04 laptop that could run TF2 flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that this is an odd issue from 2015. It was just recently brought back. Thanks for nothing ubuntu community for telling me that I was below the minimum specs when that clearly wasn't true. So I had to fix it myself.

https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/2/666826703693809496/
You run the following command and then boot the game again. It will run fine afterwards as far as I can tell.
sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386